# Basheclipse installation issue

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-mars

I installed the shellED plugin in eclipse and now I can't get basheclipse to work. I download the zip file, which contains 2 jars and a _DEBUG.sh. The instructions are:

1. Install the plug-in jars net.sf.basheclipse.core_1.0.2.v20110926.jar and 
   net.sf.basheclipse.ui_1.0.2.v20110926.jar in the Eclipse 3.7 plug-in directory (i.e. eclipse/plugins). Delete old version.

//..steps related to shellED which is already installed (and it's working I can run scripts) ...//

3) Copy the file "_DEBUG.sh" to project folder.

4) Insert the following text to the top of the file "script.sh":

. _DEBUG.sh

5) If the file is created in the Windows then sure to execute the File -> Convert Line Delimiters To -> Unix.

6) Set up a debug launch configuration
Run -> Debug Configurations -> Bash script...
Here is my problem: I did copy the 2 jars in the /usr/share/eclipse/plugins/ folder, but in the debut configuration window I don't have any Bash script section.

Any idea what I did wrong? I am running eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I wasn't putting the jars in the right plugins folder. I was copying them in /usr/share/eclipse/plugins but they have to be in /opt/eclipse/plugins.